# generator tree like augury angular 2

Tags: angular, view, tree, components, structure

I am documenting my project and I would like to add some docs to be easier in the future for the begginers understand the structure of the project. I am using angular2 and documenting with Typedocs. The question is: Is there any solution, plugin, etc... which creates you a tree view of your components (parent-child relation) as Augury does?

Here I let an image as Augury realize show this:

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated it! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is Compodoc (https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc) which seems to do what you want, but in my opinion, it's still too ugly as it is...